# How do i combine my form id variable with a .val() declaration?

Tags: jquery

I have a form which has an id of update-user1 where 1 is a variable number added dynamically to the form.

I get the id of the form like so:

```
 var myform = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');
```

How would i combine `myform` with this:

```
 var user_id =  $(myform '#user_id').val();
```

I have tried adding a + between myform and '#user_id' but that does not work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do need to do that, as Identifers must be unique, You can directly use `$('#user_id').val();`

Comment: Do you have a `user_id` ID in multiple forms? You can't do that because IDs have to be unique. You should use `class="user_id"` instead.

Comment: @Barmar yes i do, i will change them now and see if that will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
var myform = '#' + $(this).closest("form").attr('id');
var user_id = $('#user_id', myform).val();
```

Or:

```
var myform = $(this).closest("form");
var user_id = $('#user_id', myform).val();
```

Comment: The seond argument to `$( )` can't be a selector, it has to be a DOM element or a jQuery object. So your first version won't work.

Comment: You are wrong, buddy: [http://jsfiddle.net/ys3wjcgk/](http://jsfiddle.net/ys3wjcgk/). In fact, the second argument references to a parent element, and you can use a string selector or an element.

Comment: OK, it's an undocumented feature. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context says _A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context_. But it works because `$(x, y)` is implemented as `$(y).find(x)`, and that will parse `y` as a selector.

Comment: But since it's undocumented, you shouldn't depend on it or recommend it.

Comment: Precisely, since it works as `$(y).find(x)`, you can pass a string selector. I thought is a normal practice. *`Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so  $( "span", this ) is equivalent to  $( this ).find( "span" ).`*. Using that information, `$('a', '#b')` should be completely valid since `$('a').find('#b')` is valid too.

Comment: That's just an accident of implementation. If they change the implementation, it won't work any more. It's not a documented way to call it, so there's no expectation that it will work in the future.

Comment: Well, while it works internally with `.find()` it will work. It is working from `1.x` versions. Anyway, you are right, if it changes internally, it won't work.

Comment: I am glad if it works for your purposes. Anyway, take note of that @Barmar commented. I used this selector since its first versions (If I am right, since `v1.0`) and still works in the latest one. Anyway, *the usual* is to work with one version for each project; I mean, A project made with `v2.1.4` will use that version until a possible (project) update, so, this method is still usable. And... Take note too to comments that indicate you that an ID must be unique 

Answer (score 1):

As Identifiers must be unique, You don't need to use form

*Just use* [ID Selector ("#id")](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can concatenate like this way

```
$("#"+myform+" #user_id").val();
```

or use find

```
 $(this).closest("form").find('#user_id').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine like this:

```
var user_id =  $('#' + myform + ' #user_id').val();
```